# Overwriting multiple date partitions in parallel to BigQuery table from pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a dataframe in spark with a datetime column named `ymd`. I want to write the data from each of the date partitions in my Dataframe to a BigQuery table using the `ymd` column to overwrite to specific partitions in my BigQuery table. Currently I am using a for-loop, but this is very slow:

```py
def date2ymd(d: dt.datetime) -> int:
    """Convert a date to ymd format."""
    return int(f"{d.year:04}{d.month:02}{d.day:02}")

unique_timestamps = spark_df.select("ymd").distinct().collect()

for timestamp in unique_timestamps:
    print("*** Booking Time ***")
    print(timestamp.ymd)
    df_subset = spark_df.where(f"ymd = '{timestamp.ymd}'")
    output = f"my-sandbox.my-dataset.parallel_partitions${date2ymd(timestamp.ymd)}"
    df_subset.write.format("bigquery").option("writeMethod", "indirect").mode("overwrite").save(output)
```

My current approach was to use `concurrent.futures` in Python as so:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from itertools import repeat
import datetime as dt

def partition(input, n):
    # this function just partitions an input list into 'n' chunks
    for i in range(0, len(input), n):
        yield [i.ymd for i in input[i : i + n]]

def write_single_partition(partition, df):
    df_subset = df.where(f"ymd = '{partition}'")
    output = f"my-sandbox.my-dataset.parallel_partitions${date2ymd(partition)}"
    df_subset.write.format("bigquery").option("writeMethod", "indirect").mode("overwrite").save(output)

def multithread(task, partitions, df):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(task, partitions, repeat(df))
    return results

spark_df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("./my_large_partition_data.json")
dates = spark_df.select("ymd").distinct().collect()
workers = 10
chunks = list(partition(dates, workers))
rdd = sc.parallelize(chunks, numSlices=workers)
results = rdd.map(lambda x: multithread(write_single_partition, x, spark_df)).collect()
```

Which gives me this error: `Could not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers.`

I understand that this is coming from the fact that I am loading the data into a DataFrame via the `SparkSession` and this can only be present on the driver node. But my question is then, how can I distribute all of the date partitions of my dataset across the executor nodes?

I have also tried to use a pandas_udf, which does help me achieve parallel execution, but the partitions are each converted into a pandas DataFrame, so for large partitions that don't fit into memory, this will not be viable.

Comment: BigQuery engine is a bit more powerful than your python cluster. Write the dataframe to BigQuery and merge the two using SQL/DML: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax